# Implementation of 3D object rotation using open GL ES in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview

I have implemented 3D object rotation using open GL ES in android.The image is shown in emulator and its working fine. But in device, image is not visible.

Give any suggestion to go ahead.

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private GLSurfaceView glView;  // Use subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      // Allocate a custom subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)


    glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
      setContentView(glView);  // Set View (NEW)
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
    //  glView = (MyGLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceViewID);

      glView.onPause();
   }

   @Override



protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
   //   glView = (MyGLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceViewID);
      glView.onResume();
   }
}
```

This is my GLSurfaceView class

```
 package com.example.object_rotation;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
/*
 * Custom GL view by extending GLSurfaceView so as
 * to override event handlers such as onKeyUp(), onTouchEvent()
 */
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
       MyGLRenderer renderer;    // Custom GL Renderer

   // For touch event
   private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320.0f;
   private float previousX;
   private float previousY;

   // Constructor - Allocate and set the renderer
   public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      renderer = new MyGLRenderer(context);
      this.setRenderer(renderer);
      // Request focus, otherwise key/button won't react
      this.requestFocus();  
      this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   }

   // Handler for key event
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {
      switch(keyCode) {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:   // Decrease Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY -= 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:  // Increase Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY += 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:     // Decrease X-rotational speed
            renderer.speedX -= 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:   // Increase X-rotational speed 
            renderer.speedX += 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:           // Zoom out (decrease z)
            renderer.z -= 0.2f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z:           // Zoom in (increase z)
            renderer.z += 0.2f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:  // Select texture filter (NEW)
                renderer.currentTextureFilter = (renderer.currentTextureFilter + 1) % 3;
                break;
      }
      return true;  // Event handled
   }

   // Handler for touch event
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent evt) {
      float currentX = evt.getX();
      float currentY = evt.getY();
      float deltaX, deltaY;
      switch (evt.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Modify rotational angles according to movement
            deltaX = currentX - previousX;
            deltaY = currentY - previousY;
            renderer.angleX += deltaY * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
            renderer.angleY += deltaX * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
      }
      // Save current x, y
      previousX = currentX;
      previousY = currentY;
      return true;  // Event handled
   }


 }
```

This is my GLRenderer class

```
package com.example.object_rotation;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

   private Context context;
   private TextureCube cube;
   int currentTextureFilter = 0;  // Texture filter (NEW)
   // For controlling cube's z-position, x and y angles and speeds (NEW)
   float angleX = 0;   // (NEW)
   float angleY = 0;   // (NEW)
   float speedX = 0;   // (NEW)
   float speedY = 0;   // (NEW)
   float z = -6.0f;    // (NEW)

   // Constructor
   public MyGLRenderer(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      cube = new TextureCube();
   }

   // Call back when the surface is first created or re-created.
   @Override
   public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
      gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Set color's clear-value to black
      gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);            // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
      gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);    // The type of depth testing to do
      gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  // nice perspective view
      gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading of color
      gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);      // Disable dithering for better performance

      // Setup Texture, each time the surface is created
      cube.loadTexture(gl, context);    // Load image into Texture
      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  // Enable texture
   }

   // Call back after onSurfaceCreated() or whenever the window's size changes.
   @Override
   public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
      // NO CHANGE - SKIP
     // ......
   }

   // Call back to draw the current frame.
   @Override
   public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
      // Clear color and depth buffers
      gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      // ----- Render the Cube -----
      gl.glLoadIdentity();              // Reset the model-view matrix
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -2.0f, z);   // Translate into the screen (NEW)
      gl.glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
      gl.glRotatef(angleX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Rotate (NEW)
      gl.glRotatef(angleY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Rotate (NEW)
      cube.draw(gl, currentTextureFilter);

      // Update the rotational angle after each refresh (NEW)
      angleX += speedX;  // (NEW)
      angleY += speedY;  // (NEW)
   }
}
```

This is my TextureCube where i am creating my cube

```
package com.example.object_rotation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
/*
 * A cube with texture.
 * Three texture filters are to be set up. 
 */
public class TextureCube {
   private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer; // Buffer for vertex-array
   private FloatBuffer texBuffer;    // Buffer for texture-coords-array

   private float[] vertices = { // Vertices for a face
      -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
       1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
      -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
       1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f   // 3. right-top-front
   };

   float[] texCoords = { // Texture coords for the above face
      0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom
      1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom
      0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top
      1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top
   };
   int[] textureIDs = new int[3];  // Array for 3 texture-IDs (NEW)

   // Constructor - Set up the buffers
   public TextureCube() {
      // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. An float has 4 bytes
      ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
      vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
      vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert from byte to float
      vertexBuffer.put(vertices);         // Copy data into buffer
      vertexBuffer.position(0);           // Rewind

      // Setup texture-coords-array buffer, in float. An float has 4 bytes
      ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4);
      tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
      texBuffer.put(texCoords);
      texBuffer.position(0);
   }

   // Draw the shape
   public void draw(GL10 gl, int textureFilter) {  // Select the filter (NEW)
      gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);    // Front face in counter-clockwise orientation
      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face 
      gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    // Cull the back face (don't display) 

      gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
      gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  // Enable texture-coords-array
      gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define texture-coords buffer

      // Select the texture filter to use via texture ID (NEW)
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[textureFilter]);

      // front
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // left
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // back
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // right
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // top
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      // bottom
      gl.glPushMatrix();
      gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
      gl.glPopMatrix();

      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
      gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
   }

   // Load an image and create 3 textures with different filters (NEW)
   public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
      // Construct an input stream to texture image "res\drawable\crate.png"
      InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image17);
      Bitmap bitmap;
      try {
         // Read and decode input as bitmap
         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
      } finally {
         try {
            istream.close();
         } catch(IOException e) { }
      }

      gl.glGenTextures(3, textureIDs, 0);  // Generate texture-ID array for 3 textures (NEW)

      // Create Nearest Filtered Texture and bind it to texture 0 (NEW)
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
      GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

      // Create Linear Filtered Texture and bind it to texture 1 (NEW)
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[1]);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
      GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

      // Create mipmapped textures and bind it to texture 2 (NEW)
      gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[2]);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
      GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST); 
      if(gl instanceof GL11) {
         gl.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL11.GL_TRUE);
      }
      GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

      bitmap.recycle();
   }
}
```

Comment: IMO, Too little info for anyone to answer.

Comment: I can share code if u need

Comment: That would help, but anyway did you check for openGL errors ?

Comment: @concept3d here is part of code

Comment: edit your question to post the code. Please don't post it as an answer.

Comment: ok actually my progam is running in emulator with out any error. so how could i find now why it is not showing in phone

Comment: you need to check for errors using glGetError(). Because this might work in emulation mode, and still fail on hardware.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you have the subclass of argument for GLSurfaceview. It really is not needed. Neither is your random call to GLSurfaceview (NEW) and the whole findViewById thing in onResume and onPause? You shouldn't need that either. But that may not be the fix still. We would need to see the code for MyGLSurfaceview as well

Comment: @SonarSoundProgramming This is my GLsurfaceVie class can u pls have a look aat it and let me know any changes

Comment: @user3081695 It looks like your SurfaceView code should work. Maybe it is a problem with your rendering code. Check your MyGLRenderer class, assuming thats where all the drawing code is performed that is where you should find your problem. Don't be afraid to throw logs to keep track of where your application is in the process. This should help you better pinpoint the problem

Comment: @SonarSoundProgramming i have posted my renderer code can you pleaselet me know why is it not working in phone.But in emulator it is working fine no error is shown in logcat.

Comment: @user3081695 A couple of things come to mind. When loading the images you forget a min_filter on one texture. Not sure if it is necessary as I just typically avoid excluding one or the other. One thing I know can be a pest with OpenGL is that it isn't particularly nice to textures if they aren't power of 2 dimensions. If the textures are not 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 etc. by 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 etc. then you may require the use of GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two. Or you can put the texture inside a power of 2 texture and change the parameters on how you load the textures. Remember, Google is your friend

Answer (score -1):

```
private float[] vertices = { // Vertices for a face
  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
   1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
  -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
   1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f   // 3. right-top-front
};
```

I suggest to change it into

```
private float[] vertices = { // Vertices for a face
  -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0001f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
   1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0001f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
  -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0001f,  // 2. left-top-front
   1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0001f   // 3. right-top-front
};
```

In some device, if the camera position has the same z value as the vertices, the polygon will not show at all. I think this may be the problem.